# DevExpress Winform Tabheader background color

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I am using DevExpress 17.1.5 with Winforms.

I have been searching everywhere and I do not find the Docking Container for the element that holds the tabs in the Winform DexExpress framework. The goal is to set its color.

[image: Image from DevExpress website]
It should be the "Docking Container 3" but impossible to find how to set the background color of the element.

[image: This space]

This is where I want to change the color of the element.

Comment: DevExpress support is awesome... but why would you want to do that? Once they change the skin to DevExpress Dark, your background will look silly.

Comment: Requirement for the application. And we disabled all other themes.